# Facing Error with Typescript Context Provider while making it into a function and accessing the user object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context, react-tsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrzlG.png)I am new to typescript and at points I don't understand why am I getting the error really sorry If I am unable to explain it , (however will try my best).

This is the Context code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsPoo.png)

```
import {User,DashboardContextType} from "../types/user.type"



export const DashboardContext = createContext<DashboardContextType | undefined>(undefined);


export function useUserContext(){
    
    const user = useContext(DashboardContext);

    if(user === undefined){
        throw new Error("User not found");

    }


    return user;

}

interface Props{
    children?:React.ReactNode
}

export function DashboardContextProvider({ children }:Props) {
    const [user, setUserData ] = useState<User | undefined>(undefined);
  
    const contextValue: DashboardContextType = {
      user,
      setUserData: (userData: User) => setUserData(userData),
    };
  
    return (
        <DashboardContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        {children}
        </DashboardContext.Provider>
    )
  }
```

This is the login page where the hook **useUserContext** will be used to set the user data.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
//The below code imports the hook 
import { useUserContext } from '../contexts/User.context';

export default function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    //Accessing the setUserData to set the user 
    const { setUserData } = useUserContext();


    const handleEmailChange = (e:any) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    };

    const handlePasswordChange = (e:any) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Add your login logic here using email and password state values
        console.log('Email:', email);
        console.log('Password:', password);
         //the user is set here
        if (email === "kaushikc44@gmail.com" && password === "12345678") {
            const Userdata = {
                email,
                password
            }

            setUserData(Userdata)
            setEmail('');
            setPassword('');
        }

        
    
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className='justify-center items-center text-xl absolute top'>
                <h1 className='border-2'>Login Page</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input
                            type='email'
                            value={email}
                            onChange={handleEmailChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <input
                            type='password'
                            value={password}
                            onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

The type of the user is this

```
export type User = {
    email:string;
    password:string;
}

export type DashboardContextType = {
    user:User | undefined;
    setUserData: (userData:User) => void;
}
```

Had to create a DashBoardcontexttype based on chatgpt suggestion so I can use the setUserdata function in the provider to set the data.

**ERROR**  THAT I AM GETTING

***Cannot find namespace 'DashboardContext'*** && ***Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.***

Comment: is your file which contains `DashboardContextProvider` saved as a `.tsx` or as a `.ts`? (it should be `.tsx`)